# How to retrieve source code HTML CSS without inspect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an "edit box" where the user can write text/emoji, add different color background, add image,etc...

When the user has finished I would like him to be able to send his "creation" by email, so I need to get the HTML CSS of the edit box.

I tried to do some research about that but I always end up on example which uses the inspector dev tool or some extension of the browser, however I need it to be done "automatically"

Thanks

Comment: what do you call an "edit box" ?  what technologies did you use ? is it HTML+JS website ? Did you use a text editor library like summernote ? or is it a "div" with *content-editable* enabled ?

Comment: It's pure HTML/SCSS/Javascript, you can drag element inside but it's done with javascript also and no editor library was used

Comment: You could get the HTML code with `element.innerHTML` (element being the "edit box") but I don't know if you'll get the styles right or if you will need to use `window.getComputedStyle(element)` like @JP_ suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `window.getComputedStyle(element)` method to retrieve the CSS values of a DOM element. The mdn web docs have a few examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle